# Why my jasper report values are only on first page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am newbie in jasper report.
I have a problem regarding with jasper report. The values results from query must be on the second page instead of over crowding at the first page but I can't make them go to the next page. I mean they are overflowing with each other at the first page. Nobody wants to another page.  :( thanks in advance

Comment: your question doesn't seem to have proper structure,please correct or post a code sample

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide codes. My guess is the position type is not set to float. Go to properties of the element thats overflowing then set

```
Position Type : Float
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep all the text field in "Summary Band" to get all the results from query.